# NServiceBus: how to send a message from one domain to another one

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

Please, Can you help me?

There are two services which send messages to a remote queue using NServiceBus.

The first service is located in the first domain (**server1**).
The second service is located in the second domain (**server2**).
The remote queue is located at the third server (**server3**) in the second domain.

I can send messages from **server2** to **server3**.
But when I try to send messages from **server1** to **server3** I always get this error:

```
Common.Logging.ConfigurationException: The destination queue 'queue@server3' could not be found. You may have misconfigured the destination for this kind of message (Messages.Message) in the MessageEndpointMappings of the UnicastBusConfig section in your configuration file. It may also be the case that the given queue just hasn't been created yet, or has been deleted. ---> NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException ---> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: Insufficient resources to perform operation.
at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(Object obj, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
at NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.ISendMessages.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.ISendMessages.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address)
at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(IEnumerable`1 addresses, String correlationId, MessageIntentEnum messageIntent, Object[] messages)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(IEnumerable`1 addresses, String correlationId, MessageIntentEnum messageIntent, Object[] messages)
at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(Address address, String correlationId, MessageIntentEnum messageIntent, Object[] messages)
at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IBus.Send(Object[] messages)
```

Both domains are located in the same network. I can ping **server3** from **server1**, so I don't understand why NServiceBus can't find the destination queue.

I've tried to use MSMQ direct format to specify the destination queue address. But NServiceBus doesn't support it.

Comment: Your queue address queue@server3 does not have any domain qualification. What about queue@server3.domain.local

Comment: I've tried to use this format also but it's no difference. I can ping server3 from server1 using "ping server3" and using "ping server3.domain". I've used both variants.

Comment: It may be work trying MQPing also: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731852(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I don't know what the reason of this issue was. I've tried everything. All settings were valid. It started to work only after I've rebooted server1 (Ohhh, it was another big problem to do that). I don't know why.

Comment: I would also check the firewall rules, perhaps ask your system admins to do a trace. In my last workplace they turned off all ports by default in usr and prod environments so we had to go through the exercise of turning them on. Also, it probably worth noting that DTC traffic can be blocked by firewalls which might prohibit messages from reaching their destination. HTH.

Comment: Hello pax, you might want to consider posting the solution as an answere to your original question and then mark it as the solution: [link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 0):

User has answered the question him self with:

> don't know what the reason of this issue was. I've tried everything.
>   All settings were valid. It started to work only after I've rebooted
>   server1